# Gremlin query to sum 2 or more values

Tags: gremlin

I need to write a gremlin query that can sum 2 or more properties on a set of vertices and return them as separate values.

**Statement 1:**

```
g.V().has('label1').values('p1').sum()
```

This will return the sum of the p1 values of all the 'label1' vertices - let's say that's 100

**Statement 2:**

```
g.V().has('label1').values('p2').sum()
```

This will return the sum of the p2 values of all the 'label1' vertices - let's say that's 200

**Statement 3:**

```
g.V().has('label1').values('p1','p2').sum()
```

Tried the above statement, but as expected that doesn't work, it will return 300, the sum of all p1, and p2 properties of 'label1'

I need a query that will return the sum of p1, and the sum p2 in one result. Maybe there's a way I could "collapse" or fold a set of vertices into one vertex and aggregate properties by certain rules... in my case for sum.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on Daniel's original answer, this is the query that solved it for me:

```
g.V().has('label1').union(values('p1').sum(), values('p2').sum())
```

Answer (score 7):

You can group all values by their key:

```
g.V().has("label1").properties("p1","p2").
  group().by(key).by(value().sum())
```

**EDIT**

Proof that it works:

```
gremlin> g = TinkerGraph.open().traversal()
==>graphtraversalsource[tinkergraph[vertices:0 edges:0], standard]
gremlin> g.addV().property("p1", 1).property("p2", 10).iterate()
gremlin> g.addV().property("p1", 2).property("p2", 20).iterate()
gremlin> g.V().properties("p1", "p2").group().by(key).by(value().sum())
==>[p1:3,p2:30]
```

Comment: Thanks Daniel! 
None of your options work, they all return '300' in the end but... Slightly modifying the second one works: `g.V().has('label1').union(values('p1').sum(), values('p2').sum())`
If you want to change the answer with the above statement I will accept that

Comment: This new query doesn't run at all :(

Comment: Check the update. Not sure why it didn't work for you.

Comment: interesting, maybe something weird in the DataStax implementation? Here's the error I get: `System Error
org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.driver.exception.ResponseException: com.datastax.bdp.graph.impl.element.relation.SimpleProperty cannot be cast to org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.structure.Element`

Comment: Which version of DSE are you using?

Comment: I believe it's 5.1

Comment: That's weird. I tried to reproduce it in 5.0 and 5.1, but it worked in both versions. Would it be possible for you to share a Studio notebook through a public URL?

Comment: sorry for the delay, not sure how I can share the notebook without exposing our own data structures. For now, the query I derived from your original one works nicely..